# Getting the error "expected identifier or '(' before '{' token in C

Tags: c, token

Any help would be great!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define pi 3.14159



int main()
{
  float r;
  char PI;

/*Program for circumference. */

    printf(" This is a program that will calculate circumference.\n");
    printf("Please put in your radius.\n");

    scanf("%f", &r);
    printf("Please input PI\n");
    PI = getchar();
 }

   {
    if {(char != PI || 3.14);
    printf("Incorect value\n");
}

    else {
    printf("Thank you, the circumference is now.\n");
    printf("%f", (r) * pi *2);
}


return 0;

}
```

I'm trying to figure out this error, I have definitely searched around, but nothing really has popped up with my specific problem. If it helps, it is right before the "if" statement begins. Might I be using one too many '{'?

Comment: Main is terminated at `PI = getchar();
 }` from then on every bracket is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it, should I use that later on? Do you think maybe scanf("PI\n"); Make more sense? Since it's user input?

Comment: @MarkusAndrewWhite If you use `scanf()`,it should be `scanf("%c",&PI)` not `scanf("PI\n")`

Comment: @Armin Really?Is that the only error you saw?

Comment: @MarkusAndrewWhite Dude,it's nice to know you are in the US Army,and still so interested in programming despite the time constraints of such a demanding job!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pointed out the errors with  comments.Make it a habit to use caps for the `#define` macro, not for the variables.And finally, the condition for your `if` should be `if(PI!=pi)`.Remove the `{` between `if` and the `(`, and also the `;` after the `)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define pi 3.14159



int main()
{
  float r;
  char PI;

/*Program for circumference. */

    printf(" This is a program that will calculate circumference.\n");
    printf("Please put in your radius.\n");

    scanf("%f", &r);
    printf("Please input PI\n");
    PI = getchar();
 } //This is the source of error as `main()` ends after this `}'

   {
    if(PI!=pi)  //You have used a `;` after if's condition & an extra '{' before it
    printf("Incorect value\n");
}

    else {
    printf("Thank you, the circumference is now.\n");
    printf("%f", (r) * pi *2);
}


return 0;

}
```

Comment: @MarkusAndrewWhite I am afraid there are further errors in your code.Let me check again.wait...

Comment: @MarkusAndrewWhite Hey Marcus, here's the correct program  http://ideone.com/WFGyQA   I didn't edit it here as otherwise pointing out the incorrect lines and syntax would be difficult.

Comment: @MarkusAndrewWhite A lot of stuff in your program is redundant.Further,it is tricky to expect the value of `pi` entered and the value `#define`'d to match as `pi` is not a precise number.Since you seem very new to C,given your understanding of `scanf()`,let's not deviate from the main question you asked.You are welcome to post further questions if you have further doubts.

Comment: @MarkusAndrewWhite Run that code I posted in ideone.com on your compiler and give the radius as input when prompted.

Answer (score 1):

You are terminating your main function at the first `}` character. You have an uneven match of open and close braces and that is causing the problem. You also have a problem with your `if` statement. This

```
if {(char != PI || 3.14);
```

should read as

```
if (char != PI || 3.14)
```

or more specifically the entire if-else should be

```
if (char != PI || 3.14)
{
   printf("Incorect value\n");
} else {
   printf("Thank you, the circumference is now.\n");
   printf("%f", (r) * pi *2);
}
```

Comment: That fixed my other error, now I am getting expected expression before 'char'. Any input.

Comment: @mathematician1975 Are you sure `if(char !=PI||3.14)` is proper C syntax?What does it mean?I just don't understand how one can declare some clumsy expression as `char` type inside a `if`'s condition!!

Comment: @SheerFish Yes it is pretty meaningless, clearly I was just trying to point out the syntax mistakes that when corrected allow the code to compile. I agree that testing equality of a `char` and a `float` is pretty meaningless but it is not for me to guess what his code should do. I was just trying to get it to compile and then the user can work out the runtime errors in the code according to what he needs.