# Why am I getting the error "Break statement not within loop or or switch."?

Tags: c, loops, break

This simple program asks the use's age and based on that displays a message.At the end if it,the user is asked if he would like to repeat the whole thing again.But I am getting the error

> Break statement not within loop or switch

when I compile it. What does that mean and how do I correct it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int prompt_continue (const char *prompt)
   {
       printf("%s", prompt);
       char answer[5];
       if (scanf("%1s", answer) != 1)
     return 0;

       if (answer[0] == 'y' || answer[0] == 'Y')

{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    ;
    return 1;
}
return 0;
   }

   int main(void)
{
/*Creates a simple program using if else example. */



int age;

   while (printf("Welcome, this program is designed for if else statements.\n"));
   printf("Please enter your age.\n");

   scanf (" %d", &age); /*Enters age.*/
   if (age < 18){
   printf("You are young!\n");
}

else if (age > 18){
    printf("Ah you're old!\n");
  }

  {
    printf(" Woot.\n");
    if (prompt_continue("Do you want to try again? Y/N") == 0)
    break;
  }



   return 0;
}
```

Just trying to work through this, need a little help.  Did I use the while loop wrong? Any thoughts would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hey,wait a minute, you are the US army guy right?I had answered one question of yours before....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257109/getting-the-error-expected-identifier-or-before-token-in-c

Comment: When you provide code, please indent it properly. This is completely unreadable. And maybe if you'd take that habit for your code directly, that would already show you the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the scope of your loop. In this code:

```
while (printf("Welcome, this program is designed for if else statements.\n"));
printf("Please enter your age.\n");
...
if (prompt_continue("Do you want to try again? Y/N") == 0)
    break;
```

what you actually need is:

```
while (true)
{
    printf("Welcome, this program is designed for if else statements.\n"));
    printf("Please enter your age.\n");
    ...
    if (prompt_continue("Do you want to try again? Y/N") != 1)
        break;
}
```

`break` stops the execution of `while` loop here.

Comment: thanks, really appreciate that. That makes more sense.

Comment: Now, I have a question, it runs fine with no errors; but, if you were to compile it, after it asks if you want to redo the program, no matter what you type in, it just exits. What should I do now, I feel like I spent all this time working on this and now it wont even loop! Haha

Comment: How would I do that? Using bool? Maybe using enum? Or no.

Comment: @MarkusAndrewWhite: You need some good book. BTW check my answer now :)

Comment: It's all a learning experience to me, I know I don't know the language fully, but I am trying to learn some basics, and a little bit of advanced techniques, before I start taking my Computer Science classes, I'm trying to learn this language, and get a head start, and this has all definitely helped.

Comment: LihO, you know that bool/true/false only hides the fact that it's integers, with the side effect that `== true` doesn't work as one might expect, right?

Comment: @Kevin: What I meant was not to use integers in terms of that function at all.

Comment: It's c, there is no `bool` type, it's just a typedef, usually of `char` or `int`. You can't use `bool` without actually using an integer type.

Comment: @Kevin: Ah, now I understand what you mean :) I removed my first comment to prevent any further confusion of future visitors ^^

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your break statement does nothing because it is not in a loop or switch, why did you put it there.

Comment: Guess I used it wrong, hah, thanks. I thought it would be in the while loop, thanks, now that you kind of said it like that... makes me feel stupid.

Comment: I just want to know what your intention was so I can help

Comment: Yeah, like LihO said, I wanted to stop the execution, not saying you intentionally made me feel stupid, I just was expressing it. Haha, thanks for your guys' input though!

Answer (score 1):

It's just what your error say!!`break` statement has to be within the body of a `loop` , `if`  or `switch-case`  and takes the control out of that block.This is what you should use here instead of break if you want to end the program at that point:

```
 exit(0); //0 means successful termination, non-zero value means otherwise.
```

I am afraid your program needs an overhaul if you want the whole thing to repeat again.The logic is faulty.Let me check...

**Edit** Well,here's your full working program.I am sure you will understand the changes made.Else tell your confusions (if any) in a comment.Here's a brief explanation of the changes:

Th `return` statements in your `prompt_contineu()` function needed a little change,the `getchar()` there was not needed at all, there was no condition in the `while` loop in the `main()` function and its body was not well defined within `{}`, and last but not the least, the `prompt_continue()` function needed to be  invoked within the `while` loop to get the job done.I hope you can see what the `continue` statement does. By the way this evil program said I am **FRIGGIN OLD** :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int prompt_continue (const char *prompt)
   {
       printf("%s", prompt);
       char answer[5];
       if (scanf("%1s", answer) != 1)
     return 0;

       if (answer[0] == 'y' || answer[0] == 'Y')

{
    return 2;
    if (answer[0] == 'n' || answer[0] == 'N')
    return 3;
}
return 0;
   }

int main(void)
{
/*Creates a simple program using if else example. */



int age;

   while (1)
   {
   printf("Welcome, this program is designed for if else statements.\n");
   printf("Please enter your age.\n");

   scanf (" %d", &age); /*Enters age.*/
   if (age < 18)
   printf("You are young!\n");

   else if (age > 18)
    printf("Ah you're old!\n");

    printf(" Woot.\n");
    if(prompt_continue("Do you want to try again? Y/N")==3)
    break;
    else
    continue;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Jeesh, thanks! I must have used something wrong one time or another, probably before int main(void). I'm still new to all this and learning so thank you!

Comment: @MarkusAndrewWhite Check out the working version of the program and the changes made.If you have further confusions,put it up in a comment.I'll see to that once I return from a bath.